# permission denied during installation of Android SDK

Tags: android-sdk

During installation of android SDK the permission problem appears. It says permission denied.snapshot attached as follows.How to resolve this problem?

[image]

Comment: Did you try it with `sudo`?

Comment: no, i am a new user on ubuntu. doesn't know many thing.

Comment: if you know then please guide me

Comment: Repeat that command like this: `sudo ./android `

Comment: cd  /media/zohaib/01D0BABD567AD460/android-sdk-linux/tools then write sudo ./android but it says there is no command found

Comment: Show us the permissions on the file with ls -l  /media/zohaib/01D0BABD567AD460/android-sdk-linux/tools/android  and also the permissions on the mounted device from the output of the mount command (looking for noexe which prevents all execution on the device).

Comment: -rw------- 1 zohaib zohaib 3498 @ubfan1

Comment: Are you trying to install the SDK onto the phone's SD card and run it from there?

Answer (score 1):

You can run any command with `sudo` in order to give **s**uper **u**ser privileges to that command. So here you can write `sudo ./android` and then it asks your password.

Before that please check if your file `(android)` has executable permission or not. You can check that with `ll android` similar to the image below:

[image]

If there is not executable permission you can add x permission with this command: `chmod +x android`.

And you're done.

Comment: i tried it it asks password after all it says there is no command found\

Comment: ll android shows -rw------- 1 zohaib zohaib 3498. whats it mean?

Comment: also tried chmod +x android. it again shows permission denied

Comment: try with `sudo chmod +x android`

Comment: again permission denied?

Comment: What media do you use? Is it an USB device?

Comment: No usb but i installed dual OS window + ubuntu

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37679/discussion-between-zohaib-siddique-and-mahdi-a).

Answer (score 0):

From http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/adding-packages.html which I assume is the step you are on as you used `cd tools`

> Mac/Linux: Open a terminal and navigate to the tools/ directory in the location where the Android SDK was installed, then execute `android sdk`

Try using `android sdk` instead of `./android`

Comment: i write /tools android sdk but it shows permission denied

Comment: permission denied

Comment: how to give permission ? @user1326419

Comment: Try downloading the sdk onto your hard-drive instead of the mounted drive and trying from there.

Comment: I copied sdk to my Downloads location but again it says command not found @ user1326419

Comment: It is possible that your mounted drive has restricted permissions, and by copying the sdk from the mounted drive you have also copied the restricted permissions. Try downloading afresh from [link](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) to your hard-drive. Although I am surprised @Mahdi a's suggestion of running the command `sudo chmod +x android` didn't fix it.